# insert into from three different tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql

i am trying to insert data in one table from three different tables.
How can i do it in one command and not in three 'insert into' commands?

```
drop table osm_street;
CREATE TABLE osm_street 
( 
Postleitzahl text,
Ort text,
Strasse  text,
Hausnummer text
);
insert into osm_street (Postleitzahl, Ort, Strasse, Hausnummer)
select "addr:postcode","addr:city","addr:street", "addr:housenumber"
from planet_osm_polygon;

    insert into osm_street (Postleitzahl, Ort, Strasse, Hausnummer)
    select "addr:postcode","addr:city","addr:street", "addr:housenumber"
    from planet_osm_point;

    insert into osm_street (Postleitzahl, Ort, Strasse)
    select plz99,"addr:city",line.name
    from planet_osm_line as line , post_pl
    where ST_Intersects(ST_SetSRID(post_pl.geom, 4326), `ST_Transform(way,4326));`
```

Comment: I guess 4 columns of 3 tables have same datatype, isn't it ?

Comment: Simply use a `union all` to combine the three select statements (and a single `insert` of course)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If datatype of each columns in the tables are same then you can use following way

```
drop table t if exists;
create table t(id int);
insert into t(select 2 union all select 3 union all select 5);
```

---

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5eaa0/1)

So your insert statement should be

```
  INSERT INTO osm_street (
        SELECT "addr:postcode"
        ,"addr:city"
        ,"addr:street"
        ,"addr:housenumber" FROM planet_osm_point

    UNION ALL

        SELECT "addr:postcode"
        ,"addr:city"
        ,"addr:street"
        ,"addr:housenumber" FROM planet_osm_polygon

    UNION ALL

        SELECT plz99
        ,"addr:city"
        ,line.NAME,'' FROM planet_osm_line AS line
        ,post_pl WHERE ST_Intersects(ST_SetSRID(post_pl.geom, 4326), `ST_Transform(way, 4326))
        )
```

Comment: The parentheses around the select are unnecessary (and I personally find them _very_ distracting)

Comment: this code is very good, but in the third insert i have only two columns. i get an error because of it.